# AWS powershell get volumes - attachment instanceid

Tags: amazon-web-services, volumes

I trying to list all AWS volumes and get the instance that it is attached to, via powershell. I'm running a powershell program shown below that has account root privileges.

Using the documentation:

a. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TVolume.html 

b. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/TVolumeAttachment.html
 
I'm using the code:

```
$volno=0
foreach ($i in Get-EC2Volume) { 
    ++$volno
    write-host $i.VolumeId $i.Name $i.Size $i.VolumeType
    write-host $i.Atachments.Count
    foreach ($j in $i.Atachments) {
      $j.InstanceId
    }
  }
```

I get these results:

```
vol-83d1e111  10 gp2
0
vol-2248a222  8 gp2
0
vol-4b48a333  30 gp2
0
vol-345fbf44  50 gp2
0
vol-b4876b55  8 gp2
0
....
```

### Questions

1. The results show there are no attachments, that is, all volumes are not attached to any instance. Some of the volumes are attached to running instances. Why?

   Reference a. shows that there is a property 'Attachments' which has a type of `System.Collections.Generic.List` 

   and 

   Reference b. shows that `Amazon.EC2.Model.VolumeAttachment` has a member of `InstanceId`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there was a typo which I did not notice:
write-host $i.Atachments.Count
should be
write-host $i.Attachments.Count

and

foreach ($j in $i.Atachments) {
should be
foreach ($j in $i.Attachments) {